# Dimensional analysis for a theory with a single mass scale

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, conformal-field-theory, dimensional-analysis, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I am reading this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.02714) on $T\overline{T}$ deformation and have a question about eq.(2.7),
\begin{align}
\mu \frac{dS}{d\mu} =\frac{1}{2\pi}\int d^{2}x\ \sqrt{g}T^{i}_{i}.\tag{2.7}
\end{align}
The authors claim that dimensional analysis for a theory with a single mass scale leads to the above equation, but I don't understand why. This may be obvious to many people, but I would like a detailed explanation.